# How to get information from select options and input, another input?

Tags: javascript

How to copy input, select in other input all together ?

I have image please check for more information.

[image]

Comment: please , provide little more elaboration

Comment: if you have code snippet , provide it

Comment: i don't have code im searching but not found

Comment: Well you read the values from the individual fields, and then use some basic string concatenation to bring them into the format you want, and then you write that into the target field … none of that is actual rocket science, and how the basic steps work, is something you should be able to research yourself … you are not the first person ever to try and read the values from form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I can properly answer to your question. Here is the following code, written in Angular.JS

**Script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[])



myApp.controller("myController",function($scope){

    $scope.cartype="";
    $scope.caryear="";
    $scope.carcolor="";
    $scope.carvalue="";
});
```

demo.html

```
<html  ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <title>welcome</title>
    <script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- ng-app is an directive  which autobootstraps angularjs application
its a starting point of angularjs application -->
<body ng-controller="myController">


        car type: <input type="text", ng-model="cartype"/>
        car year model: <input type="text", ng-model="caryear"/>
        car color: <input type="text" , ng-model="carcolor"/>
        car value: <input type="text", ng-model="carvalue"/>

        final : {{cartype}}
                {{caryear}}
                {{carcolor}}
                {{carvalue}}

      </body>
      </html>
```